# Scala Filter a map for based on unique values within Map values

Tags: scala

In Scala, I'm trying to filter a map based on a unique property with the Map values.

```
case class Product(
  item: Item,
)
productModels: Map[Int, Product]
```

How can I create a new `Map` (or filter `productModels`) to only contain values where `Product.Item.someproperty` is unique within the `Map`?

I've been trying `foldLeft` on productModels, but can't seem to get it.  I'll keep trying but want to check with you all as well.

Thanks

Comment: To make sure that I understand. As an example, replacing `Product` with `String` for simplicity, you'd expect `f ( Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar", 3 -> "foo", 4 -> "bippy")` to output `Map(2 -> "bar", 4 -> "bippy") )` since `"foo"` shows up as a value for keys `1` and `3`?

Comment: Thanks for question.  I'd expect `Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar", 4 -> "bippy")` because these are the unique values

Comment: Please, can you rephrase it once again, do you need to filter your map and leave only entires that **had** unique product's field in original map, or you want to calculate map where there is strictly one entry for each distinct product's field value from original map (discard duplicates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to transform your map into another map, where keys are desired fields of `Item`:

```
case class Product(item:String)

val productModels =
  Map(
    1 -> Product("a"),
    2 -> Product("b"),
    3 -> Product("c"),
    4 -> Product("a")
  )

// here I'm calculating distinct by Product.item for simplicity
productModels.map { case e@(_, v) => v.item -> e }.values.toMap
```

Result:

```
Map(4 -> Product(a), 2 -> Product(b), 3 -> Product(c))
```

Note, that the order of the elements is not guaranteed, as generic `Map` doesn't have particular order of keys.  If you use `Map` that has item order, such as `ListMap` and want to preserve order of elements, here is the necessary adjustment:

```
productModels.toList.reverse.map { case e@(_, v) => v.item -> e }.toMap.values.toMap
```

Result:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Product] = Map(1 -> Product(a), 3 -> Product(c), 2 -> Product(b))
```

Comment: Not clear whether OP wants to preserve only the entries that had unique values in original map or just remove entries with duplicate values, leaving exactly one entry per unique value.

Comment: I'd like one entry per unique value.  If it helps, I'm trying to replicate a Ruby function uniq.  So, in this case, something like `nv = productModels.uniq | |pm| pm.item[:distinct_property] }`

Comment: This `productModels.map { case e@(_, v) => v.item -> e }.values.toMap` seems to be working so far.  Wow.  what does the `e@` do?

Comment: @ToddM it's the way to create alias for your result (or partial result) in pattern matching.  For example, `case (_, v) =>` just matched the tuple, `case e@(_, v) =>` additionally makes the tuple available as `e`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the following way:

```
productModels
  .groupBy(_._1)            // produces Map[Product, Map[Int, Product]]
  .filter {case (k,v) => v.size == 1} // filters unique values
  .flatMap {case (_,v) => v}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Item(property:String)
case class Product(item:Item)
val xs = Map[Int, Product]() // your example has this data structure

// just filter the map based on the item property value
xs filter { case (k,v) => v.item.property == "some property value" }
```

Comment: This assumes I know what I'm looking for in `some property value`, right?  I'm looking for distincts

Comment: Are you saying that the map has duplicate values with different keys?

Answer (score 0):

Here is implementation with `foldLeft`:

```
productModels.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Product]){ 
  (acc, el) => 
    if (acc.exists(_._2.item.someproperty == el._2.item.someproperty)) acc 
    else acc + el
}
```